# Fetch all records with duplicated virtual attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How to write an ActiveRecord query which would return all records with duplicated virtual attributes?

For instance, suppose the user.rb model has the following virtual attribute:

```
def fullname
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

How to fetch all users with the same `fullname`?

Comment: You can't use ActiveRecord for that. "Virtual" attributes cannot be queried against, you can only filter by them in Ruby once the models are all instantiated. You'll have to write a bit of SQL by hand to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arel functionality to write some mysql functions in ruby

```
def self.fullname_col
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new "CONCAT_WS", [ ' ', arel_table[:first_name], arel_table[:last_name] ]
end

scope :fullname, ->(name) { where(fullname_col.eq(name)) }
```

then you can search through this scope

```
User.fullname('Your name')
```